# Displaying Max value and ID Number attached to it

Tags: mysql

I'm working on using aggregate functions in mysql and have run into a problem: I want to take the maximum value in a column and display it alongside the ID Number that maximum value is attached to.

So, I have a few columns. One contains an ID Number, one contains hours worked, and one contains funds raised (It's a test database of a fictional volunteer organization). Basically, I want to take whoever volunteered the most hours and display the number of hours they worked with the ID Number.

I can display the max hours just fine using this code:

`SELECT MAX(HoursWorked) AS 'Most Active' FROM HoursWorked`

However, when I try adding a function to find that ID Number, I either get an error or an ID Number that I do not want (I know it's the one I don't want because I looked at the table beforehand and know which ID Number is the one with the maximum hours).

How do I word it to fix the error?

Comment: Is there only one entry in HoursWorked for each volunteer? You may need SUM not MAX.

Comment: @JacobH There's one entry in the HoursWorked column for each volunteer, and the correct entry pops up when I want to display just the max number. However, it wouldn't help in a real world application if it didn't say who it belonged to, which is what I want to do.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea would be to do it in two steps

- find the max value
- find the rows where HoursWorked = max value

This can be done using the statement below with subquery:

```
SELECT id, name, HoursWorked FROM HoursWorked where HoursWorked = (select max(HoursWorked) from HoursWorked);`
```

In the subquery you are looking for the biggest value of HoursWorked using aggregate function max(), and then in main query you are trying to find all the rows where HoursWorked value is equal to this previously found max value.

This way you are able to identify the situation when two or more volunteers are the most active (the same number of hours worked)

Comment: Worked exactly as I wanted it to. I tried something similar to that, but I just didn't have the right syntax. Oh, the joys of learning. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are not grouping by any fields then you can pick the highest `HoursWorked` by sorting in descending order as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, HoursWorked FROM HoursWorked ORDER BY HoursWorked DESC
```

Comment: Would that be considered an Aggregate Function? This is for a class and I have to use aggregate functions (not specifically what I'm trying to do, but I want to do that because it's one of the things I've said I can use the database for throughout the course)

Comment: No, this would not be considered as aggregate.